# No Difference in Done Click and Pause Click in YTPlayerView iOS SDK

Tags: ios, ytplayerview

I am using YTPlayerView iOS Helper Library (0.1.4 and 0.1.5 is having issue in playing video) for playing video within my app,

I figured out that, there is no difference between pause button click and Done button Click, I want to get difference from the SDK itself without adding any Observers or adding a transparent button over Done button.